# Laravel resource controller, return page with message after store()

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have made a page that registers a new company for my system and will then depending on the output return a message to the user. I have now changed my routes and location for php to a resource controller but I am now getting a problem with redirecting to other pages. I want to redirect to my Companies/create page with a message that can say with variables attached to tell the result of the registration.

I have looked at the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-named-routes) but can't get it to work properly.

Can somebody help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code in your controller as well?

Comment: Can you put some of the codes of what you are trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any message with `with()` method like this:

```
return view('some.view')->with('message', 'This is a message');
```

Then in a view:

```
@if (session('message'))
    {{ session('message') }}
@endif
```

Or:

```
{{ session('message') or '' }}
```

Comment: I should've concidered this earlier but the problem with this solution is that I'll stay on the same url but only with a different view so this technically doesn't answer my question. This works for me though.

Answer (score 1):

```
return view('some.view')->with('message', 'This is a message');

{{ $message ?? '' }}
```

or

```
\Session::put('message', 'This is a message');
{{ session('message') }}
```